Displaying Text on Paper
I'm printing out something like 400 sheets of paper through MATLAB, and I'd like to be able to display the slice number in the corner of the paper. I've attached a preview of what one of the slices will look like. The thing is, the figure doesn't cover the entire paper; the figure's only as big as the brain in the center of the paper, so it's hard to insert text outside the figure. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to put text in the bottom right corner of the paper?

For those concerned, here's the print portion of the code:
for i=1:1:slices
    fprintf('SLICE %f OF %f\n', i, slices)
    imagesc(blox(:, :, i))
    colormap(flipud(gray)) 
    axis off;

    set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [(py - dim2/10)/2 ,(px - dim1/10)/2, dim2/10, dim1/10]);
    set(gca, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);

    for j=1:10
        print(gcf)
    end
end


You can add an empty ax and use page number as the legend for that dummy ax,
axPageNumber = line(nan, nan, 'Linestyle', 'none', 'Marker', 'none', 'Color', 'none');
legend(axPageNumber, num2str(7), 'Location','southeast', 'Fontsize', 20)
legend('boxoff') 

which results in something like this,


Hi again Zain! So, I tried that, but unfortunately the axes still seem to be adhering to the figure, so the number shows up in the corner of the figure (which really only takes up the center of the paper), not corner of the paper. Remember the size of the figure is fixed (per our previous discussion) and can't be stretched to fit the entire paper.

Hi Bell! I edited the answer with print preview result, which seems to me working. Try set(gcf, 'PaperOrientation', 'landscape'); and if it changes the output result, you probably need to modify your paper position.

Hi again Bell, if this didn't solve your problem, can you provide a reproducible example like you did for your previous question? The output results are very different with different image size and page setting.

It's okay! I kind of just resigned to having the text in the corner of the figure instead of the corner of the paper. I was having too many issues with it and I think at some point my brain convinced myself that the number looked better closer to the image, anyway.
